# Angular child update parent and ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, angular7

So I understand the 'why' of getting the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` on Angular, but I just can't figure out how to fix it based on the articles I'm reading.  What I have is a service that defines an observable like so:

```js
private classification = new BehaviorSubject<string>('Assumed to be A');
public hazardClassification$ = this.classification.asObservable();

public setClassification(value: string): void {
    this.classification.next(value);
}
```

In the child component, which is where I determine the value, I'm setting it from the `ngOnInit`:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.hazardClassificationService.setClassification(this.hazardClassification);
    this.valueChanges = this.thisTabFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(() => this.hazardClassificationService.setClassification(this.hazardClassification));
}
```

In the parent component I grab that observable like so:

```js
ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
    this.hazardClassification$ = this.hazardClassificationService.hazardClassification$;
}
```

and then display it in the parent's HTML via `hazardClassification$ | async`.

What I've tried so far is assigning the observable, in the parent, in `ngOnInit`, `ngAfterContentChecked` and `ngAfterContentInit`.  None of them are the right spot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call `this.classification.next(value)` inside`setTimeout`:

```js
public setClassification(value: string): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.classification.next(value);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks much.  I used a `Promise.resolve().then` in place of the `setTimeout`.